# VBA altering SQL statement in nested conidtional statements

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I have 2 lists of items, 1 is client ID and the other is National insurance number and ive been asked to make a clever SUB which will check the database for both ID and NI and if theres a result copy the data, if no result try ID and if no luck with ID try NI as a last resort
I have tried this with the code below, start with a query looking for information based on the current cells ID and NI, if result copy it into cell and done, if no result do the same query but just with ID if result copy else try NI etc..

I keep getting the recordset error not allowing it to be used whilst open but ive added closes after each situation but still nothing.

is this idea viable and if so whats missing fro my code for it to do what i want it to do

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rec As ADODB.Recordset
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rec = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim sql As String
Dim client As String
Dim NI As String

Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Dim msgStr As Variant
Dim f As New Details_Bar

Set myRange = Range("A2:A502")

Dim x As Integer
x = 1
pos = 2

With con
    .Provider = "MSDASQL"
    .ConnectionString = "DSN=ukfast"
    .Open
End With

' Loop Start
For Each myCell In myRange

client = myCell.text
NI = Cells(myCell.Row, 2).text

    ' First Look
    sql = "SELECT id,firstname,lastname,national_insurance FROM crm_clients WHERE id = '" & client & "' AND national_insurance = '" & NI & "' GROUP BY id"

    rec.Open sql, con
    ' If Record Found Auto Enter Data in cells
    If Not (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then

    Cells(myCell.Row, 7).CopyFromRecordset rec

    rec.Close

    MSG1 = MsgBox("Data Was Automatically Found", vbOKOnly)

    'Else Begin to query the database again based on the Client ID

    Else

        sql = "SELECT id,firstname,lastname,national_insurance FROM crm_clients WHERE id = '" & client & "' GROUP BY id"

        rec.Open sql, con

        'If no result on ID then try NI Number

            If (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then

                sql = "SELECT id,firstname,lastname,national_insurance FROM crm_clients WHERE national_insurance = '" & NI & "' GROUP BY id"

                rec.Open sql, con

                Cells(myCell.Row, 100).CopyFromRecordset rec

                MSG1 = MsgBox("The Following Data Was Found About Client based on NI" & x & vbNewLine & "Client ID : " & Cells(myCell.Row, 100) & vbNewLine & "First Name : " & Cells(myCell.Row, 101) & vbNewLine & "Last Name : " & Cells(myCell.Row, 102) & vbNewLine & "National Insurance : " & Cells(myCell.Row, 103) & vbNewLine & "Is this correct?", vbYesNoCancel, "Data Check")

                Select Case MSG1

                Case vbYes
                    Cells(myCell.Row, "G").Value = Cells(myCell.Row, 100)
                    Cells(myCell.Row, "H").Value = Cells(myCell.Row, 101)
                    Cells(myCell.Row, "I").Value = Cells(myCell.Row, 102)
                    Cells(myCell.Row, "J").Value = Cells(myCell.Row, 103)
                Case vbNo
                    Details_Bar.Show
                Case vbCancel
                    Exit For
                    Exit Sub

                End Select
                rec.Close
            End If

        Cells(myCell.Row, 100).CopyFromRecordset rec

        MSG1 = MsgBox("The Following Data Was Found About Client based on ID" & x & vbNewLine & "Client ID : " & Cells(myCell.Row, 100) & vbNewLine & "First Name : " & Cells(myCell.Row, 101) & vbNewLine & "Last Name : " & Cells(myCell.Row, 102) & vbNewLine & "National Insurance : " & Cells(myCell.Row, 103) & vbNewLine & "Is this correct?", vbYesNoCancel, "Data Check")

            Select Case MSG1

            Case vbYes
                Cells(myCell.Row, "G").Value = Cells(myCell.Row, 100)
                Cells(myCell.Row, "H").Value = Cells(myCell.Row, 101)
                Cells(myCell.Row, "I").Value = Cells(myCell.Row, 102)
                Cells(myCell.Row, "J").Value = Cells(myCell.Row, 103)
            Case vbNo
                Details_Bar.Show
            Case vbCancel
                Exit For
                Exit Sub

            End Select
        rec.Close
End If


' Update Vars
pos = pos + 1
x = x + 1
'End Of Loop
Next myCell

GUI.CommandButton13.Enabled = False
GUI.CommandButton15.Enabled = False
Range("CA502:CZ502").Select
Selection.Delete
Range("A1").Select
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the solution.

Like some of my previous work i came to realize that the record needs to always be closed at just before the end of the loop and with each different conditional statement it has to be closed at the beginning of every conditional statement and immediately re-opened after the new query for it then to be closed outside of all conditional statements

```
' First Look
    sql = "SELECT id,firstname,lastname,national_insurance FROM crm_clients WHERE id = '" & client & "' AND national_insurance = '" & NI & "' GROUP BY id"

    rec.Open sql, con
    ' If Record Found Auto Enter Data in cells
    If Not (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then

    Cells(myCell.Row, 7).CopyFromRecordset rec

    rec.Close '<--------------- Previous location

    MSG1 = MsgBox("Data Was Automatically Found", vbOKOnly)

    'Else Begin to query the database again based on the Client ID

    Else
        rec.close <-------------- New location

        sql = "SELECT id,firstname,lastname,national_insurance FROM crm_clients WHERE id = '" & client & "' GROUP BY id"

        rec.Open sql, con
```